# replace this bbcode with this bbcode

Tags: php, regex

Basically I am trying to convert xenforo's forum script database over to my custom one (dropping my use on xenforo) and their bbcode is annoying me.

I am trying to change all the url bbcode from theirs to mine with this:

```
$message = preg_replace("/\[url\=\'(.+?)\'\](.+?)\[\/url\]/is",
                        "[url=$1]$2[/url]", $message);
```

Basically they have single quotes surrounding the urls i don't want them but my code doesn't work.

Comment: Please show an input example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use double quotes for your regexp string, you must double escape, because PHP interprets backslashes as well

```
$message = preg_replace("/\\[url='(.+?)'\\](.+?)\\[\\/url\\]/is",
                        "[url=$1]$2[/url]", $message);
```

Test case

```
<?php
$message = "[url='http://www.example.com/test']My test URL[/url]";
$message = preg_replace("/\\[url='(.+?)'\\](.+?)\\[\\/url\\]/is",
                        "[url=$1]$2[/url]", $message);
echo "$message\n";
```

and its output

> [url=http://www.example.com/test]My test URL[/url]

The test is done on Ubuntu 12.04 and with PHP 5.3.10.

Comment: That doesn't work 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in /home/gamingon/public_html/prxa.info/xenforo_convert.php on line 65

Comment: @LiamDawe See updated answer. So, there must be an error somewhere else.

Comment: Will that work when there are more than one? Maybe that's my issue.

Comment: @LiamDawe Try it yourself. Append another `[url]` at `$message`. It will be changed as well.

Comment: I ask as it doesn't work for me and i was thinking that was the issue.

Comment: @LiamDawe The example test case doesn't work? Or it doesn't work in your environment?

Comment: I managed to find my issue, this works sorry to bother you :)